# strange crystal report summation issue for columns

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to sum all the column value and want to display a summary. I am choosing Insert -> Summary -> Column name and Sum.. But rather then showing sum it is counting the rows and displaying the rows. Kindly please suggest some solution. I am available here if some one need for more info to help please comment. (Sap Scn Crystal Report)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are selecting the sum option from the summary?, because normally this should have returned the sum of the values. As an alternative you can use a Running Total Field.

- From the Field Explorer window, right click on the "Running Total Fields" and select "New".
- In the window that will appear, on the left side you will see the available tables and fields. From there select the field that you want to sum up and press the top ">" button.
- As a type of summary select "sum", type a name for the "Running Total Name:" and press OK.
- Drag and drop the new Running Total Field on a section of your report.

Comment: Tried it, result are same. Same counting.

Comment: Check the datatype of the field, if it's not numeric then you should cast it before getting the sum.

Comment: After a long fight , i changed each field to numeric type and then sum them all.. Too long process but worked. I wonder i took all the fields as numeric , and they were behaving like numeric but are not condsidered numeric my crytal report